# When integrity of an Exchange 2013 mailbox database is questionable, is it safe to simply "move" the mailboxes, or do they have to be exported?

Tags: email-server, exchange-2013, exchange-server

I have an Exchange 2013 database which contains some mailboxes, and I'm getting this error in the Event logs

*Database  has been offline-repaired (by eseutil.exe) one or more times in the past. However, although this ensures database-level logical consistency and may permit the database to be successfully mounted, Exchange-level logical consistency can no longer be guaranteed. Therefore, all mailboxes should be evacuated from the database and the database should be retired as soon as possible in order to eliminate the potential for unexpected behaviour caused by Exchange-level logical inconsistency.

This event will continue to be emitted once per hour while the database is mounted as an urgent reminder to evacuate and retire the database as soon as possible.*

Now, my question is, can I simply move the mailboxes to another database via the New-MoveRequest command and that will restore the integrity of the mailboxes, or do I have to go through this complicated import/export process described in the below link:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633455(v=exchg.150).aspx

Also, I see that .pst files have a file size limit of 50 gb.  Are there any size limit on New-MoveRequests or migration of mailboxes in general?  For example, one mailbox I want to move is 75 GB - is that OK to do?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `can I simply move the mailboxes to another database` - Yes. `or do I have to go through this complicated import/export process` - No.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no size limit for mailboxes with the New-MoveRequest command.

I would highly recommend using this tool before trying to perform an export/import of PSTs. Move requests are very simple, and are easier to work around errors with. PST exports can be effective for certain scenarios, but then you have to deal with multiple steps instead of one step *and* the risk of large PST corruption.

The only problem that you may end up with is corruption of individual items within some mailboxes. This is not uncommon, and can be worked around by raising the limit on how many corrupt items you want to allow to be skipped (not migrated) before the move operation fails.

Comment: I've done a few recoveries and this has been my experience. If you can mount the mailbox DB *at all* then move mailbox is the most robust method of getting data out - though it can't do much about any corrupted messages themselves, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

No while searching on the size limit, not find the specific solution but the problem occurs when you try to import the large(50) GB file into Outlook Application. As Outlook has some limitation of file size according to version, even outlook can be hanged or not run properly. So need to whether use the split PST file.

Or To Avoid that you need can filter the content including in the mailbox such as emails details, contacts, Calendar details. for that, you can go for **New-MailboxExportRequest**. Parameter needed with Mailbox Request Command, use [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/New-MailboxExportRequest?view=exchange-ps) . All commands are given below that can help while exporting data.

And if you want to Save **Effort and Time** use [**Visit**](https://www.techcolite.com/export-mailbox-from-exchange-to-pst-file-save-effort-time/) while Exporting large exchange mailbox by splitting them into multiple smaller PST files.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no size Limit when using  New-MoveRequest command but if the database contains any corrupt items then the process will fail. For this you need to use "BaditemLimit "  and "AcceptLargeDatabase" parameters.